# Gatling Report non-html Request Customization

Tags: scala, gatling

In gatling, all the non-html resources being requested is reported in the result file (see attached image).How do I exclude these resource request from being reported in the result file to make the report look tidy.

Secondly, I have all the non-html resources blacklisted as below, but it still makes requests to get them. Is that the expected?

```
val httpProtocol = http
        .baseUrl("https://abc")     
        .inferHtmlResources(BlackList(""".*\.js""", """.*\.css""", """.*\.gif""", """.*\.jpeg""", """.*\.jpg""", """.*\.ico""", """.*\.woff""", """.*\.woff2""", """.*\.(t|o)tf""", """.*\.png""", """.*detectportal\.firefox\.com.*"""), WhiteList())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For exclude resources from report just add `.silentResources` to protocol.
   There you can read more about it https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/protocol/#silencing
2. Your resource contains characters ***after*** type. Example: `....css?v=d0edd...`, so you need to rewrite regex:
   instead `.*\.js` write `.*\.js.*`

Comment: Thanks heaps for you response @Amerousful. That really helped.